# Mercurial Dummy Push

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way with Mercurial to do a dummy push?

I basically want to see what would happen in the event that I did a push with my current changesets.

I remember this type of functionality being available in Subversion but I'm not sure how I'd go about it with Mercurial.

The reason for this is that I'd like to see how many changes are being pushed to how many files etc etc, all of the info that's shown during a real push.

Perhaps there's a better way of doing this that I don't know about yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `hg outgoing`.